# How to make Quantity remember interpretation?

Tags: units

Units with micro `μ` prefix needs internet connection to interpret. For example,

```
Quantity[1, "μm"]
```

[image]

Though after one such interpretation, `Quantity` remembers it. However, it only remembers it in this particular kernel session. Is it possible to make `Quantity` remember such interpretation for all future kernel sessions?

Comment: Use `"Micrometers"` instead?

Comment: BTW, people here generally like users to post code as *Mathematica* code instead of just images or TeX, so they can copy-paste it. It makes it convenient for them and more likely you will get someone to help you. You may find [the meta Q&A, How to copy code from Mathematica so it looks good on this site,](http://meta.mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/1584) helpful

Comment: @MichaelE2 Thank you for reply. I know "Micrometers", and I know I need to try to post code, but I thought the blue part should better shown in image, so I just post them together in one image  : )

Comment: I knew you knew that, :).  I just went to copy the code, and I couldn't.  I'll just assume it doesn't work.  Though maybe it does?

Answer (score 7):

I suggest using `"Micrometers"`, but if not, this works in V13.0.1:

```
Block[{QuantityUnits`$UnitAlternateStandardNameReplacements = 
   Append[QuantityUnits`$UnitAlternateStandardNameReplacements, 
    "mum" -> "Micrometers"]},
 Quantity[1, "mum"]
 ]

(*  Quantity[1, "Micrometers"]  *)
```

Use whatever string you prefer instead of `"mum"`.

Comment: This is great. Thank you so much. I do not know QuantityUnits`$UnitAlternateStandardNameReplacements has this feature : )

Comment: @matheorem You're welcome. It is internal, undocumented, and subject to change, of course.